# img tag with Resource Files and asp:literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, localization

I am having a weird issue that I can't seem to fix. I am using WebForms and .NET 4.5.

I have a bunch of Images in an Images folder in my root directory. These images are each in a folder corresponding to some local. It looks like this.

```
Root

    -Images

        -en-US

            -flag.jpg

        -es-MX

            -flag.jpg
```

I am using resource files to store the image paths.

Now the actual issue is that I am unsure how to use relative paths to define the img src in conjunction with the resource file. Normally I could put runat="server" in the img tag and that would let me specify src="~/somepath but since I am using an asp literal as part of the source it does not seem to interpret the tag correctly. If I don't use the ~ (root), the resource wont load as soon as the user changes to a page that is not in the root directory because it tries to load it based on the new location. For example: someurl/UserPages/Images/flag.jpg <= should be someurl/Images/Flag.jpg.

Here is what my img tag looks like:

```
<img src="~/Images/<asp:Literal ID="test" meta:resourcekey="test" runat="server" Text="" />" runat="server" alt="Flag" height="42" width="42" />
```

That does not work at all because it interprets the path as

```
http://ipaddr:port/~/Images/
```

I have tried implementing this using jQuery to set the src of the img tag and it did not fix the problem.

These are some of the KB articles I have tried to use to fix my problem with no success.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

[HTML img and ASP.NET Image and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190769/html-img-and-asp-net-image-and-relative-paths)

[How to use image resource in asp.net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244807/how-to-use-image-resource-in-asp-net-website)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1677822.aspx/1

[Image localization in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532276/image-localization-in-asp-net)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

**EDIT:**

I tried putting images in the resource file itself but after some digging I found that this is not a good solution for web applications. Still stuck with my original problem. :(

Still no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
your_asp_literal.Text = "<img src='"+ GetGlobalResourceObject("your_resx_file", "your_picture_path").ToString() + "' alt='your_alt' height='42' width='42'/>";
```